# Selecting 2 or more rows using an array (PHP, MYSQLi)

Tags: php, mysqli

Ok, I wasnt sure how to title this.

I have 2 tables, one with products and one with merchants.

Some products can be sold by 2 or more merchants.

The products table has a column called 'product_merchant_id' with 1 or more references in it, like so.. '1237, 38272, 3738'

The id's are related to whats in the 'merchant_id' column in the 'merchants' table.

Merchant Table (merchants)

```
mer_id | merchant_id | merchant_name
-------------------------------------
1    |    1237     | Merchant One 
2    |    38272    | Merchant Two
3    |    3738     | Merchant Three
```

Product Table (products)

```
product_id   |   product_merchant_id   |  product_name
------------------------------------------------------------
    1        |   1237, 38272           |  Sample Product One
    2        |   1237, 3738, 38272     |  Sample Product Two
    3        |   3728                  |  Sample Product Three
```

So, basically, if I was querying product_id 2, I want to be able to pull 2 rows with the merchant_id's of 1237 & 38272 from the merchant table and loop them in my template, something like...

```
<div>
    <p>Merchant Name: Merchant One</p>
    <p>Merchant ID: 1237</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Merchant Name: Merchant Two</p>
    <p>Merchant ID: 38272</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like your database isn't normalized because of `product_merchant_id` has multiple values separated by `,` which make it a bit harder to query a database as far as I know

Comment: Thats kinda how I was trying to do it. I thought it would be more simple to to have the merchant ID's in an array for each product. Do you think I should use a separate table?

Comment: You should really have another table that matches your suppliers to the products. eg: `id`, `supplier_id`, `product_id`. Then you could use JOINs to get the information you want.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that too just after I read the first reply.. I edited my reply at the same time you (@Jono20201) answered.

Comment: very bad database structure

Comment: Its much bigger and more complex than that @kefy, I just used the above for simplicity of showing on here.

Comment: Great, -1 me for asking a question? Whats the point in -1'ing someone for trying to learn something? very helpful indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to change your table structure. Remove the `product_merchant_id` column in the Product table, then create a new table, called `product_merchants`, with two columns: `product_id` and `merchant_id`. It will look something like:

```
product_id | merchant_id
--------------------------
1          |    1237 
1          |    38272
2          |    1237
2          |    2728   
2          |    38272   
3          |    3738
```

Now, you can use a join to get all the information you need. Something like this should work:

```
SELECT m.merchant_name, m.merchant_id
FROM merchants m
JOIN product_merchants mp ON m.merchant_id = mp.merchant_id
    AND mp.product_id = 2
```

[**See demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0827/1)

Comment: Yep, I think I will go with something like this. I can use a while loop in my PHP to grab the different merchant rows in the merchant table using the info from new product_merchants table.. I will give Coder anonymous's answer a try too because its nice to know more than one way of doing something.. Learning something new every day.. Thanks All!

Comment: @EoinH Great, glad to help :) Note, if it's helpful, I just added a demo to my answer. Good luck!

Comment: Didn't see the sqlfiddle at first, thanks for taking the time to do that.. much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this can help:

```
Select * from merchants where merchant_id in ((select product_merchant_id from products where product_id=2))
```

I believe this should work.

Comment: Thanks, looks good. I will give this a shot and see how it works out.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is you can add one table that like stock table that will be mapped product_id and merchant_id and you will get stock_id it will make easier for development